# Locally isometric surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature, isometry

I have to decide whether the surface $S$ parametrized by
\begin{align*}\mathbf{x}:\mathbb{R}\times \left]-\pi,\pi\right[&\longrightarrow S\\
(u,v)&\longmapsto ((2+\sin u)\cos v,(2+\sin u)\sin v,u),\end{align*}
is locally isometric to the helicoid $T$ given by
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{y}:\mathbb{R}^2&\longrightarrow T\\
(s,t)&\longmapsto (s\cos t,s\sin t,t).
\end{align*}
Here's my attempt:

I have computed the Gaussian curvature of $S$ and got that it is
$$K_S(u)=\frac{\sin u}{(1+\cos^2u)^2(2+\sin u)}.$$
On the other hand, the Gaussian curvature of the helicoid is
$$K_T(s)=-\frac{1}{(1+s^2)^2}.$$
If $S$ and $T$ where locally isometric, then they would have the same Gaussian curvature. However, we cannot solve $K_S(u)=K_T(s)$ since $K_S$ is sometimes positive and sometimes negative, while $K_T$ is always negative. Therefore, $S$ and $T$ are not locally isometric.

**Is this reasoning correct? Thanks.**

**PD:** I've checked my computations with Mathematica and apparently the curvatures are correct.

Comment: Yes, this is basically the content of Gauß's Theorema Egregium

Comment: It doesn't hurt to visualize what $S$ is. Note that it is a surface of revolution, and it's easy to see what its profile is. This will confirm your answer.